# I get an odd figure when I try to make a figure with both one (line)plot and a bar plot at one figure

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I dont know how to handle matplotlib well.

I want to make a figure which has two data, one is line plot and the other is histogram.
And I cannot use seaborn due to my server issue for the time being.

This is my codes i've been writing.

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

ax1.plot(dat['frequency'], '-s', color='green', markersize=7, linewidth=5, alpha=0.7, label='frequency')
ax1.set_xlabel('Year')
ax1.set_ylabel('frequency')

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.hist(dat['PDO'], color='deeppink', label='PDO', alpha=0.7)
ax2.set_ylabel('PDO')

plt.show()
```

And for sure, two data has same x axis range but different y axis range.
(first one is like (0, 80) and the second one is like (-2, 1))

And the result is here below. It's literally weird.

[image]

I want to get a figure like this one, one figure with two data like this. But one is line plot and the other is bar plot.

[image]

How can I make a figure I really want?

I want to make a figure with two dataset, one is in line plot and the other is in histogram bar plot.
I've tried it quite a lot but couldn't make it.

Comment: can you provide a minimal dataset to have a reproducible example?

Answer (score 2):

If your x axis range is the same for both series, it should work:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'Year': np.random.randint(2000, 2021, 1000),
                   'Value': np.random.randint(0, 100, 1000)})

# Create your own series, just an example
s1 = df.groupby('Year')['Value'].mean()
s2 = s1 / s1.max()

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

ax1.plot(s1.index, s1, '-s', color='green', markersize=7, linewidth=5, alpha=0.7, label='frequency')
ax1.set_xlabel('Year')
ax1.set_ylabel('frequency')

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.bar(s2.index, s2, color='deeppink', label='PDO', alpha=0.7)  # bar and not hist
ax2.set_ylabel('PDO')

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]